# Get Custom style on Cross Reference's Reference Type

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm writing a quite big document that needs to have two kind of headings, one for chapters (Chapter I, I.1, I.1.1, and so on). This is achieveable using the standard Heading style and Multilevel list. But then, I need another set of heading with different numbering style (Appendix A, A.1, A.1.1, and so on). I solved the problem just by copying the standard heading style (Heading 1, Heading 2, etc) to a new style with another set of multilevel list. Works great so far.

The problem comes when I want to refer to a section in Appendix. I can't find the "Appendix" choice in the Reference type dropdown (there's an option for Heading). Here's a screenshot to clarify:

[image: Word Reference Type]

There's obviously an option for Heading that shows the list of Headings, but there's no option for Appendix there. What should I do to get "Appendix" in the reference type dropdown? I know I can just refer to the Appendix from the "Numbered List" option, but I want to make a template for this document so I can use it for other documents. I think refering the Appendix from "Numbered item" is suboptimal.

Thanks before.

Answer (score 2):

As annoying as it is, the official answer seems to be "you can't":

> The "heading" category in the Cross-reference dialog box only includes the built-in headings. What you can do is manually bookmark your appendix paragraphs as required and then insert a cross-reference to the bookmark.
>   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2016/have-new-heading-styles-appear-in-cross/6735eaff-5212-4bec-8865-30208ec4f64f

As you mentioned, Word is willing to use numbered items as well, so that's probably your best bet without custom bookmarks or diving into macros.